# How to make a variable global in Webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to import the [Politespace](https://github.com/filamentgroup/politespace) library into a Webpack project. It's written such that on a [certain line](https://github.com/filamentgroup/politespace/blob/master/dist/politespace.js#L189) it tries to attach a global `Politespace` object to the `window` object, which is needed for an event listener on the `document` object to correctly behave.

But when trying to load this in Webpack by putting an `import` into `vendor.js` I'm seeing that `w` comes out as just an object - it seems like Webpack is substituting a different variable, so that it's never attached to the `window`.

Is there a way to allow importing libraries that assign global properties to Window, other than having to copy and paste the file and modify it to refer specifically to the `window` rather than `w` (which I've verified does work)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using the [`imports-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader)

You can use it in 2 ways; either when you `require()` the library by doing something like

`require("imports-loader?this=>window!politespace");`

or by setting it up in the `webpack.config.js` like so (as per documentation)

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: require.resolve("some-module"),
                loader: "imports-loader?this=>window"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```